# Возврат к необходимой стадии работы telegram бота при его падении (python)

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Подскажите:
бот работает таким образом, что при воде определенных параметров один пользователь ждет когда другой пользователь создаст предложение удовлетворяющие условиям первого.
Реализовано все при помощи БД postgres, и соответственно при создании заявки таблица первого пользователя заполнена всеми необходимыми данными и работает функция проверки не появился ли второй пользователь соответствующий условиям в таблице первого. Так вот, при падении бота (перезагрузки сервера), бот перезапускается но у пользователя естественно функция проверки уже не работает и бот ждет когда пользователь отправит /start и ему нужно будет снова проходить все этапы программы до той же проверочной функции.

Вопрос в том как при перезапуске бота (имея ID юзера) запустить необходимую функцию (в определенной точке кода для него) и отправить сообщение определенному юзеру?

Comment: Заведите статусы пользователя для каждого этапа работы программы и на каждом этапе записывайте в отдельную таблицу(ы) в БД этот статус. При запуске бота добавьте функцию проверки этого статуса, что позволит определить последний выполненный этап для данного пользователя.

Comment: да в этом как раз проблемы нет, проблема в том чтоб в момент запуска телеграм-бота перейти к определенному этапу выполнения программы для определенного пользователя, но для того чтоб работать с определенным пользователем нужно что б он отправил месседж и потом к нему привязаться... но при запуске у бота нат информации о мессаджах пользователя(

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось в message_chat_id лежит именно ID пользователя, так что передав в этот параметр user_id из базы данных можно отправить сообщение нужному юзеру, и соответственно запустить именно для него необходимую функцию!

bot.send_message(chat_id = user_id, text = "hello!!!")